# mounting block device and multipath

Tags: rhel, multipath-storage

I have a storage unit, connected to the host server via scsi cables.  There are two controllers on the storage unit, controller-A and controller-B, each with 1 scsi cable connecting it to the host.

After creating one disk group, under controller-A, making a volume...

my choices for mapping the one volume are

- `'All Initiators'`
- `*`
- `s001-0`
- `s001-1`

If I only map to `s001-0` then my storage unit shows up via `lsblk` as `/dev/sdb`.

If I map to either `*` or `All initiators` then `lsblk` reports

```
/dev/sdb
|_ mpatha

/dev/sdc
|_ mpatha
```

It is here that I don't understand *multipathing* on how it's supposed to happen in RHEL 7.9, how do I properly mount my storage array?

I've already been successful in having just the one mapping...

- to s000-0
- then just one block device `/dev/sdb` shows up,
- I can `parted mklabel gpt`
- `parted mkpart -a optimal primary 0% 100%` to get just `/dev/sdb1`
- Then do `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1` followed by `mount /dev/sdb1 /data`.

*how do I properly make use of multipathing, under RHEL 7.9, when I map my one storage volume to `all initiators`* to correctly mount my storage unit?

Answer (score 0):

Just mount the `/dev/mapper/mpatha` device if you use it without partitions or to mount the partition it will be `/dev/mapper/mpatha1`.

Multipath devices in RHEL are managed using [multipathd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/multipathd) daemon and device mapper multipath. The `mpathX` device created by dm-multipath is a virtual device "connecting" the two paths, you can use it directly, it's there just as an easy/convenient way to tell "these two drives are actually one connected via two paths so you shouldn't use them separately".

If you want to an easy way to mount the drive no matter how it is connected (one or both paths), you can mount it using the filesystem label or UUID and then use the `/dev/disk/by-uid` or `/dev/disk/by-label` symlink.